# is A pure javascript framework on J2EE projects possible?

Tags: javascript, ajax, gwt, jakarta-ee, rhino

I've been working in the j2ee field for several years and tired of writing all those AJAX functions which downloading some data from server-side and render on the client-side.

Is it possible to only write javascript codes that run on both server-side and client-side.

like, if I need to develop a login page, I can write a piece of code kinda like this:

**ORIGINAL CODE:**

```
remote checkPassword;


function checkPassword(username, password){
    if(existsRecord("select 1 from staff_t where user_name=? and password=?",username, password))
        return true;
    return false;
};

var main(){
    var userName=$("username").val();
    var password=$("password").val();
    if(checkPassword(userName,password))
        alert("Welcome, "+ user);
    }else{
        alert("sorry, wrong username or password.");
    }
}
```

In the code above, javascript gets the data from dababase directly, isn't it clearer and easier to understand?

While this code actually runs on production mode, it is separated by an engine to two pieces:

**SERVER-SIDE:**

```
function checkPassword(username, password){
    if(existsRecord("select 1 from staff_t where user_name=? and password=?",username, password))
        return true;
    return false;
};
```

**CLIENT-SIDE:**

```
    var userName=$("username").val();
    var password=$("password").val();
            // 'checkPassword' has been translated to an AJAX function.
    if(checkPassword(userName,password))  
        alert("Welcome, "+ user);
    }else{
        alert("sorry, wrong username or password.");
    }
```

This way, we can use a single piece of code for a single business without separating them into java and javascript. The engine will separate the code and determine which parts should run on the server and others run on browsers.

I've searched all the internet, but didn't find any framework like that which can provide accessibility to database/EJB/WEBSERVICE.

**Google Web Toolkit (GWT)** enables us to write pure JAVA code for a browser-based application, but it seems a little clumsy for me. :)

**Rhino** is a javascript engine running on j2ee projects, but it doesn't provide any means to access both client-side data and server-side data.

does anyone know a framework like this, or is it possible to develop one all by ourselves? what's the pros and cons?

thanks.

Comment: Do you realize that JS can be disabled, hacked and spoofed (i.e. it's 100% controlled by the client)? You truly have to have *something* in the server side to catch that.

Comment: If it's pure JavaScript it won't be a J2EE project any more. If you just want to be able to use JavaScript on the server have a look at [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/). If you want to do it all in JavaScript on the client refer to BalusC's comment.

Comment: sorry, I forget to mention that the engine is suppose to separate the code into client-side code and server-side code, the server-side code will be executed by Rhino while the client-side code looks just like what we usually write. I have edited the post.

Comment: thanks for pointing out that, BalusC.  nnnnnn, I am browsing nodejs's website, thank you.  Actually, I just hate AJAX and think of a way to get rid of it, it causes many redundant code fragments all over my projects, all the functions written in Java have to be rewritten in Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to only write javascript codes that run on both server-side and client-side.

Sure, drop J2EE and come join the [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) community

As for frameworks, no. You can't magically communicate between the two. The best I've seen is automated RPC like [nodeQuery](https://github.com/tblobaum/nodeQuery) where the server sends DOM commands over RPC to a client.

Alternatively, who needs a server when you can write [couchapps](http://couchapp.org/page/index) and serve HTML directly from your database.

Answer (score 1):

A lazy solution to this is to use frameworks which have a direct binding between UI presentation and server object model. This makes it a lot easier to write validation only on server-side: you just specify the validation code in Java. AJAX makes this validation available on client side automatically (before the submit actually took place!)

If you think about it, the password example is very minimal. Most validation cases require more code and even more data. Suppose you validate the address of a user using a geographical database; will you push this full database to client side? No, you send the address to the server using AJAX and display the validation result to the user in realtime.

JSF uses this approach quite nicely (RichFaces, ICEFaces...)